# How to convert hours to days hours and minutes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have number in hours I need to convert it for days hours and minutes.

For example I have this number of hours `33.22`

I need to convert it to days hours and minutes.

The result should be `01.09:13:12`(i.e one day 9-hours,13-minutes and 12-seconds).

Currently I do this:

```
value = 33.22

var x = new Date(value * 3600000); //replace with TotalMilliSeconds in your case
var time = x.toUTCString().split(' ')[4]; //slit by space character

return time.split(':')[0] + ":" + time.split(':')[1];
```

But the result that I get wrong i think I should avoid use Date object.

How can I get days hours and minutes if I have number of hours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write a function `convert` which takes your input (hours) as parameter, convert it to seconds, calculates days, hours and minutes and finally returns the formatted string:

```
const convert = (a) => {
  let secs = a * 3600;  // get total amount of seconds from your input
  const days = Math.floor(secs / (3600 * 24));
  secs  -= days * 3600 * 24;
  const hours   = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  secs  -= hours * 3600;
  const mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs  -= mins * 60;
  console.log(`${days.toString().padStart(2,'0')}.${hours.toString().padStart(2,'0')}:${mins.toString().padStart(2,'0')}:${secs.toString().padStart(2,'0')}`);
}
```